# How to fix this Minecraft lighting problem that I am facing on version 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am on minecraft version 1.16.5, and whenever I place some sort of light source the nearby blocks start looking like this:
[image]

It just looks so ugly, the block partitions become visible and the wall loooks like it's made up of blocks of the same type but of different shades. I'm using a shader pack, but that's not causing the problem as when I turn it off the problem still persists.

Please provide some possible fix, as I am not able to put lanterns in my house anymore.

Edit: here's an interesting thing...
[image]
This is with smooth lighting set to 100% and to maximum with the shader pack disabled.

Now this...
[image]
When I removed the wall directly In front, it disappeared.
It seems like the walls are casting some sort of shadow on each other. Should I just update to 1.17 or there is some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somehow you switched off Smooth Lighting - press Esc to access the menu, Options, Video Settings, Smooth Lighting, and change it to "Maximum".

Off:
[image]

Maximum:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem still persists, smooth lighting was already set to maximum and only the smooth lighting percentage was low, I set it to hundred but the walls still look the same, I saw the difference between smooth lighting set to minimum and maximum, the walls become even more ugly when set to minimum. Is this because I am on a lower version?

Comment: @Minecraftuser No, the screenshots I posted were taken in 1.16.5, OTOH - are you using some shaders, texture packs, mods affecting rendering (Optifine, Sodium), or anything like that?

Comment: Yeah I am using a shader pack, but here's the thing, when I disable it, the lines are still visible but a little less, so the problem is there without the shader pack, do you think that the shader pack is responsible for this? Also I have optfine installed.

Comment: @Minecraftuser I think the mod that allows using the shaderpack is responsible for this. Unmodded vanilla doesn't support external shaders.

Comment: So is there any workaround through which I can use the shader without messing things up in game, also for better understanding let me tell you what I did. In the beginning I played on version 1.17 without any shaders and the problem was not there, but then I wanted to use them because it makes everything look more appealing, so i downgraded as there aren't many shaders compatible with the 1.17 yet. And then the problem started appearing, I uninstalled and reinstalled minecraft with optfine in order to run the shader, I just want to use them, is there any way I can do that without this problem

Comment: @Minecraftuser Optifine in 1.16.5, with and without shaders, can do proper smooth lighting just fine. But it has a myriad of options, and you must have enabled something that causes this problem. Unfortunately I can't tell you which of the countless options causes the problem, and this being a "technical support for modded Minecraft" issue, it's explicitly off-topic on this site.